# https on multiple virtual hosts using apache2 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: server, apache2, virtualhost, https

I've been hosting my company's web page on my server, but recently I've been asked to host another domain in the same server, so I added a virtual host on `/etc/apache2/sites-available` and it's working. BUT, if I try to access this domain using https, it opens the first domain. My virtual host .conf file goes like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com

    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/example>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

If I change `<VirtualHost *:80>` to `<VirtualHost *:443>`, apache2 fails to start.

So the question is: How do I configure this virtual host to work with both http and https?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The virtualhost file for the first HTTPS site will give you a hint about how such files should be written.

Comment: @fkraiem But off course! It was in a file named `default-ssl.conf`! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @fkraiem for the comment, I was able to solve my issue. I just had to get a look at my `default-ssl.conf` file and make a similar file pointing to my second domain.